# Can't log in into my local server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, apache2, lamp

I'm trying to install LAMP right now.

In the manual it said that if I've installed Apache I will be able to go on `http://local_server_IP`. And there is given 2 commands to get it:

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'
```

when I ran it it said that I haven't got such a device as `eth0`, I've found out, that my Ethernet interface is named `enp4s0` and ran:

```
ip addr show enp4s0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'
```

and it returns nothing.
The second command was:

```
curl http://icanhazip.com
```

it works and returns `2a02:2168:858:8001:0:0:0:5`, it is not the right value, I can't run server

```
http://2a02:2168:858:8001:0:0:0:5
```

Then I thought I need IPv4, so I found my IPv4 with site - `46.242.14.149`, I checked this:

```
http://46.242.14.149
```

It's "loading" for a very long time and can't find the page. 
So I'd be very glad if you can show me my mistake, thank you for your time :)

**UPDATE:**
Such a strange thing - now `curl http://icanhazip.com` returns `46.242.14.75`.

`ip address` output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:8a:5b:f0:42:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:e2:30:0d:ea:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.234.179.135/19 brd 10.234.191.255 scope global dynamic wlp5s0
       valid_lft 859sec preferred_lft 859sec
    inet6 fe80::54e6:9989:422c:98f6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d1:61:64:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:93:96:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, verify what addresses the webserver is actually listening to. 
Run `sudo netstat -an | grep :80`:

```
$ netstat -an | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Here I have a webserver, listening on port 80, exclusively on IPv6. A server listening on IPv4 would have tcp instead of tcp6, and it would be `0.0.0.0:80` and `0.0.0.0:*`, not `:::80` and `:::*`

0.0.0.0 is a magic address for every available IPv4 interface, and :: is a magic address for every available IPv6 interface.

On to addresses... you seem to be a bit confused by the IPv6 address you have: The IP 2a02:2168:858:8001:0:0:0:5 is your IPv6 address. Usually the IPv6 address is global, unlike IPv4 networks, where you typically employ NAT for outgoing traffic, to mask your local address. But, to use it in a browser, you need to enclose it in [], so http://[2a02:2168:858:8001:0:0:0:5] *should* work, if your webserver is set up to listen on IPv6.

To allow external IPv6 access you probably have to allow port 80 through the firewall in your network router.

Regarding the other IP you found, 46.242.14.149, this is probably your external IPv4 address. This doesn't belong to your computer, but to your router. To be able to access your website via this, you need to set up portforwarding, from the router, to your computer. Read the manual for your router for how to do this.

To show which IP the local interface actually has, the easiest is to use the command `ip address`. The output will resemble the following:

```
$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:ae:c5:09:5f:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.55/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:4661:7f30:0:beae:c5ff:fe09:5f15/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
    inet6 fe80::beae:c5ff:fe09:5f15/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As we can see, I here have one NIC, `enp2s0`, with both an IPv4 (inet) address, and an IPv6 (inet6) address. Thus, http://10.0.1.55 should work in this case - but only on the local network.

In addition, I have a loopback adapter, `lo`, with the IPv4 127.0.0.1 and IPv6 of ::1. In fact, every computer, almost regardless of operating system, has this loopback address. It always refers to the local computer. Thus http://127.0.0.1 or http://[::1] will always connect to the local webserver, over the loopback interface.

The code snippets you include in your question essentially tries to parse the output of ifconfig to show your IP address. This can be useful in some scenarios, but when you're simply checking what it is manually, it's wasted time.

Comment: Thank you very much :) - I've partially understood how it works,  I solved this problem right now - it was a silly problem about my local server. So thank you very much for your explanations :)

Comment: I grokked from what you wrote that you partially understood it, so I tried to explain the most important stuff. If something is unclear, poke me and I'll expand on it.

Comment: I ran `ip address` (I added output in quetion), enp4s0 was the thing I needed. But can you please explain what are the others, apart from lo and enp4s0, please.

Comment: Briefly it's different interfaces. docker0 is a docker interface, wlp5s0 is wifi and so on. For detailed meaning of interface names, I suggest a new question, as it is a somewhat different topic :)

Comment: I'd be glad to , but won't it take a big amount of your time? I can try to google that, if you don't want to explain that.